# Why is the law of Hooke valid only for small displacements?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, spring, elasticity, approximations

What changes when displacement exceeds a certain limit?

Comment: Well, for once at some point the spring breaks...

Comment: You get Hooke's law from a Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Two things get involved: non-linearity of the (elastic) force and irreversible deformations (lack of elasticity) that spoil the linear character of the Hooke (returning) force.

Comment: I think it's worth commenting that a lot of the well behaved linear-elastic materials are quite linear, and the non-linearity is pretty negligible in their elastic regimes.

Comment: Linearity and elasticity are different things. Elasticity is more general.

Comment: There is also viscoelasticity, which (unlike Hooke) is not a state function.